# Can one boost converter power three 5 W loads in parallel?

Tags: boost, parallel, converter, load

I want to power three 12 V/5 W light bulbs in parallel. I have a 3.7 V Li-po battery which has a discharge rate of 20 A. I have an [LTC1871](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1871fe.pdf) boost converter. Is it possible for me to power the circuit using this boost converter?

Comment: What do you mean by discharge rate?

Answer (score 0):

The LTC1871 will see the three 5 W bulbs as one load; it actually can't distinguish whether there is one 15 W bulb or three 5 W ones.

Electrically it's the same, so yes, not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Calculation without losses:

Three 5 W loads in parallel make one 15 W load, as far as the power supply is concerned.

15 W at 12 V = 15/12 A = 1.25 A, so the light bulbs need 1.25 A at 12 V.

Boosting a 3.7 V input to 12 V at 1.25 A output requires 12/3.7 x 1.25 = 4 A input current.

So far, nothing the LT1871 can't handle **with the right external MOSFET** and other components, even at low efficiency.

Selecting the external MOSFET can be a bit of a pain because of how the LT1871 was designed; from the [datasheet](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1871fe.pdf):

> The power MOSFET serves two purposes in the LTC1871: it represents the main switching element in the power path,
> and its RDS(ON) represents the current sensing element for the control loop. Important parameters for the power
> MOSFET include the drain-to-source breakdown voltage (BVDSS), the threshold voltage (VGS(TH)), the on-resistance
> (RDS(ON)) versus gate-to-source voltage, the gate-to-source and gate-to-drain charges (QGS and QGD, respectively),
> the maximum drain current (ID(MAX)) and the MOSFET’s thermal resistances (RTH(JC) and RTH(JA)).

> The gate drive voltage is set by the 5.2V INTV CC low drop regulator. Consequently, logic-level threshold MOSFETs should be used in most LTC1871 applications. *If low input voltage operation is expected (e.g., supplying power from a lithium-ion battery or a 3.3V logic supply), then sublogic-
> level threshold MOSFETs should be used.*

The datasheet shows the design procedure in detail. If, however, you have a ready-built DC-DC converter module, *all depends on the specs of that module*.